# How do I change the 3DS eShop region?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-eshop

I got a 3DS XL for Christmas. However, the only things on the eShop in Costa Rica are updates! I can't change my NNID region, and the eShop refuses to load when the NNID region and 3DS profile region don't match. How do I change the region without deleting my NNID?

Comment: I have rolled back your edits because they added nothing useful to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to delete your current one, but you do have to create a new one. According to [nintendo support](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1085/~/how-to-change-nintendo-network-id-information-%28e-mail-address%2C-gender%2C-region%2C), "Nintendo 3DS family systems can only support one Nintendo Network ID at a time. However, you can format the system to deactivate the current NNID and create a new one. (The existing account and purchases will not be deleted, and can still be re-linked to the same system in the future.)"

Also, it is necessary for the system and NNID country to be the same. Other useful information can be found [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/260/~/how-to-change-the-system-country%2Fregion-setting).

Comment: +1 The key point is having the NNID setup in the right region.

Comment: I don't want to reformat my 3DS yet again [I did that once due to my uncle leaving behind a lot of junk when he gave it to me, and I'm not doing it again], so looks like my current NNID is gonna have to go bye-bye. I'll have to ask my uncle how they get all the eShop's cool stuff while I don't before going ahead and deleting my NNID, though.

Comment: ...and it's official; my NNID is now gone. I decided to recreate it under the Ontario, Canada region. Now how do I lock this question??