# Which region-free 3DS eShop countries exist, assuming they do?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-eshop

Continued on from my [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/323649/how-do-i-change-the-3ds-eshop-region), I ultimately deleted my 3DS NNID and decided to recreate it under a different region [which will have to wait until my birthday due to parental problems]. The thing is...which eShop regions can be funded with foreign credit/debit cards?? I'd like to get a full list of the region-free eShop countries before recreating my NNID, because once I set my mind on the country, I can't change it without deletion or reformatting [which is the reason my old NNID got deleted].

P.S. I'm mainly doing all of this to get 3 eShop-exclusive titles that I especially want. They cost about 31.97 USD in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just about the payment methods you can safely use *any* non-American region. For example European regions will accept your card. Only North American regions restrict their access there. The U.S. region also requires an address in the U.S., while other NA regions "only" require the credit card to be from an American country.

Comment: "American" as in "from the US" or "from the American continent"?? For reference, I live in Costa Rica, and my 3DS XL was imported from the US. [I also heard that the Canadian eShop has no currency lockout...either that or I misinterpreted it.]

Comment: According to Reddit all North American regions have that restriction to allow only American cards plus someone from Brazil as well, so it's likely to count for the whole continent. Just the U.S. has a more restrictive e-Shop requiring a U.S. home address as well.

Comment: In other words, the currency lockout only happens between the NTSC-U, NTSC-J and PAL eShops??

Comment: @JoséDanielStellerVargas U.S. payment methods should work in EU shops. The other way round they don't.

Comment: Well, if the region lockout only exists for the US in the form of the "home address" and that's it, then **why did they say on the process of NNID creation that currency not matching the eShop's country "is nontransferable and will be erased without refund if you proceed"??!!** Did they toss that in to scare pirates away from doing their thing or something??

Comment: You still need to pay in the proper currency anywhere. It's just not restricted everywhere to where the credit card is from.

Comment: They're talking about currency denomination.  This has nothing to do with where the credit card is from.  If you stored 50 Euros into your NNID, then decide to select US, the 50 Euros will simply disappear.  If you used your European CC to pay, the Nintendo eShop will charge US dollars to your card.  This gives you some % of processing feeds, but it gets processed in USD, not in Euros.

Comment: **Oh...** So they didn't mean that foreign currencies are banned from being used to fund an eShop, they meant that the funds accumulated in the eShop won't be kept if you switch regions!! Wow, am I a **big** fan of ambiguous syntax... I think we have a nominee for this question's accepted answer at this rate!!

Comment: One through reading of the NNID messages and the eShop manual later and it just so happens that they meant that balance obtained through foreign currency will be erased if the NNID is linked!! <sarcasm>OMG AMBIGOUS SYNTAX ROCKS.</sarcasm> Well, let's see if I can get the **4** titles that I want!! [Also, I recreated my NNID!! And yes, I previously said that I wanted **3** eShop titles, but I ended up adding _Animal Crossing: New Leaf_ to the wish list, racking up the total value of my cart (barring taxes) to 61.96 USD (about 34808.99 CRC).]